# Add column in ThunderBird to show the message content (initial first words)

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

I want to have a new custom column, which will be i.e. `message` or whatever.. and it will show the message (inbox) content, lets say, initial 5-6 words :

[image]

How anything like that possible?

p.s: Current ThunderBird Version: 68.2. None of wellknown (i.e.`ColumnsWizard`) extensions work on latest versions.

Comment: I don't know an answer to the question, but it may be useful to Edit the question to include the precise current version, and the list of extensions you've used in the past which you've verified no longer work with the current version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ColumnWizard, but, as you say, the new versions of Thunderbird have killed almost all the extensions we knew and depended upon

I'm still clicking on buttons that are no longer there.

As a workaround, you can move your cursor to the bottom of the message list pane and drag it up a little bit to expose the top of the message content pane. When that is visible, it will display the top of the content of whatever message is selected in the message list pane. That gets you what you want, but only for one message at at a time and you can't do anything like sorting messages on a column of message contents.

I don't use this feature because hovering on an item in the message list displayed the start of the message content and had the side effect of marking the message as read when I hadn't actually read it yet.

If you go into Edit->Preferences->Display->Advanced, you can set the number of seconds a message has to be displayed before it is automatically marked as read. This helps a little with this problem.

If you want to, you can also go to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ and file an enhancement request to have this option added to Thunderbird. However, there are only a few very dedicated and helpful developers over there and the chance of them getting to such a request is not very good.

Comment: thanks joe, nice answer. unfortunately, clicking on message is what i want to avoid and wanted a column like i said... :(

Comment: After 17 days, I figured something was better than nothing. Ot w

Comment: It wouldn't fit in a comment.